# ImageMagick processing of scan images

Tags: linux, image-processing, imagemagick, crop

I am uploading a picture of a document taken with my smartphone to my Linux server. On my Linux server I am using ImageMagick to cut the edges and do some processing (like gray color coding) to make it look like a scanned document.

Below is one sample image.

[image: sample image]

I want to trim the image so that only the paper is selected, and do further processing to make it look like a scanned image, similar to what a cam scanner does.

Note: I want the parameters for ImageMagick tool to be generic so that I can use the same command line options to process images taken under different conditions of light.

Comment: That is an extremely broad question and it is likely to take fairly considerable skills and effort to provide a method to handle different lighting, exposure, paper orientation, cropping, rectification and contrast control - almost certainly more than anyone would want to provide for 10-15 points of reputation :-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Mark.  However, I can offer a starting point that may help you get going in the right direction:

**Isolate the Paper:**
Assuming the paper is sufficiently contrasted against the background you can use something like:

```
 ## make the background transparent 
 convert 'input_image' \( -clone 0 -fill black -fuzz 10% +opaque "rgb(1,1,1)" -transparent black \) -delete 0 'transp_image'
```

You will have to change the rgb color values to match the 'white' color of the paper.  The `display` command in imagemagick has a nice utility for this.  Also you can play with the `-fuzz` percentage to isolate the paper only.

**Remove the Background:**  Hopefully the above code will make all areas outside the paper transparent in which case you can trim away the background:

```
 ## trim the transparent background away
 convert 'transp_image' -trim 'isolat_image'
```

From there you can do fancier things like changing the perspective.  Try looking into `-distort` in imagemagick (http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective).  Though I am not sure how you would apply a distortion in a loop to pictures taken by hand -- each picture would probably require specific input parameters.

Good luck!